# Javascript Cannot access class before initialization

Tags: javascript

I have the following bit of code whereby I'm using class expressions

```
const ShapeOverlays = class {
  constructor(elm) {
    this.elm = elm;
    this.path = elm.querySelectorAll('path');
    this.numPoints = 4;
    this.duration = 1000;
    this.delayPointsArray = [];
    this.delayPointsMax = 0;
    this.delayPerPath = 60;
    this.timeStart = Date.now();
    this.isOpened = false;
    this.isAnimating = false;
  }
}

(function() {
  const elmHamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger');
  const gNavItems = document.querySelectorAll('.global-menu__item');
  const elmOverlay = document.querySelector('.shape-overlays');
  const overlay = new ShapeOverlays(elmOverlay);

  elmHamburger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (overlay.isAnimating) {
      return false;
    }
    overlay.toggle();
    if (overlay.isOpened === true) {
      elmHamburger.classList.add('is-opened-navi');
      for (var i = 0; i < gNavItems.length; i++) {
        gNavItems[i].classList.add('is-opened');
      }
    } else {
      elmHamburger.classList.remove('is-opened-navi');
      for (var i = 0; i < gNavItems.length; i++) {
        gNavItems[i].classList.remove('is-opened');
      }
    }
  });
}());
```

But I'm getting the error

`Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'ShapeOverlays' before initialization`

on the line `const overlay = new ShapeOverlays(elmOverlay);` which is weird because the class has been initialized above. What I'm I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class expression is missing a semicolon.

```js
const ShapeOverlays = class {
  constructor(elm) {
    // ...
  }
}; // <-- this one
```

Working:

```js
const Test = class {
  constructor() {
    this.isOpened = false;
    this.isAnimating = false;
  }
};

(function() {
  const overlay = new Test(4);
  console.log(overlay)
}());
```

Not working:

```js
const Test = class {
  constructor() {
    this.isOpened = false;
    this.isAnimating = false;
  }
}

(function() {
  const overlay = new Test(4);
  console.log(overlay)
}());
```

Answer (score -1):

you have one too may `(...)`. So, if you moved it to the following I think it should work fine.

```
const ShapeOverlays = class {
  constructor(elm) {
    this.elm = elm;
    this.path = elm.querySelectorAll("path");
    this.numPoints = 4;
    this.duration = 1000;
    this.delayPointsArray = [];
    this.delayPointsMax = 0;
    this.delayPerPath = 60;
    this.timeStart = Date.now();
    this.isOpened = false;
    this.isAnimating = false;
  }
};
(function () {
  const elmHamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
  const gNavItems = document.querySelectorAll(".global-menu__item");
  const elmOverlay = document.querySelector(".shape-overlays");
  const overlay = new ShapeOverlays(elmOverlay);

  elmHamburger.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (overlay.isAnimating) {
      return false;
    }
    overlay.toggle();
    if (overlay.isOpened === true) {
      elmHamburger.classList.add("is-opened-navi");
      for (var i = 0; i < gNavItems.length; i++) {
        gNavItems[i].classList.add("is-opened");
      }
    } else {
      elmHamburger.classList.remove("is-opened-navi");
      for (var i = 0; i < gNavItems.length; i++) {
        gNavItems[i].classList.remove("is-opened");
      }
    }
  });
})();
```

Let me know if it does NOT help. Thanks.

Comment: This was not the root cause. The problem is fixed inside your example because you added a missing semicolon. Look at my answer.

Answer (score -1):

It works if you declare the class inside the function, its happening because you are instantly declaring and invoking the function so the scope is lexical in terms to the globally declared class. See this for reference:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE

```
(function() {
    const ShapeOverlays = class {
        constructor(elm) {
          this.elm = elm;
          this.path = elm.querySelectorAll('path');
          this.numPoints = 4;
          this.duration = 1000;
          this.delayPointsArray = [];
          this.delayPointsMax = 0;
          this.delayPerPath = 60;
          this.timeStart = Date.now();
          this.isOpened = false;
          this.isAnimating = false;
        }
      }
    const elmHamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger');
    const gNavItems = document.querySelectorAll('.global-menu__item');
    const elmOverlay = document.querySelector('.shape-overlays');
    const overlay = new ShapeOverlays(elmOverlay);
  
    elmHamburger.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (overlay.isAnimating) {
        return false;
      }
      overlay.toggle();
      if (overlay.isOpened === true) {
        elmHamburger.classList.add('is-opened-navi');
        for (var i = 0; i < gNavItems.length; i++) {
          gNavItems[i].classList.add('is-opened');
        }
      } else {
        elmHamburger.classList.remove('is-opened-navi');
        for (var i = 0; i < gNavItems.length; i++) {
          gNavItems[i].classList.remove('is-opened');
        }
      }
    });
  }());
```